# How to get active user email with installabled onEdit trigger?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Google spreadsheet with some data. I wrote script to track changes of some specific columns.

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Turn on', functionName: 'createSpreadsheetEditTrigger'}
    ];
  ss.addMenu('Tracker', menuItems);
}


function changeTrack(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ws = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
  const headerRow = 4;
  const editBodyCols = [2, 3, 4, 5];
  const fResultCol = 6;
  var range = ws.getActiveRange();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  let target1 = ws.getRange(row, fResultCol);  
  let target2 = ws.getRange(row, fResultCol + 1)
  let activeUser = getCurrentUserEmail();
  if(row > headerRow && editBodyCols.some(x => x === col) === true){
    if(target1.getValue() !== ""){
    target2.setValue(result(ss, ws, row, activeUser)[1]);
    } else {
      target1.setValue(result(ss, ws, row, activeUser)[0])
      target2.setValue(result(ss, ws, row, activeUser)[1])
    }
  }  
}

function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('changeTrack')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit()     
      .create();
}

function date(){
  return  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
}

function result(ss, ws, row, activeUser) {  
  const ssName = ss.getName();  
  let data = `Создал ${activeUser} ${date()}`;
  let exp = `Файл ${ssName}, Лист ${ws.getName()}, изменил ${activeUser}, строка № ${row}, ${date()}`;
  let adds = [];
  adds.push([data],[exp]);
  return adds;
}

function getCurrentUserEmail()
{
  var email=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  return email;
}
```

My problem is to get active user's email. This script can get it but not all the time. Seems like random success. It means sometimes I can get expected value, sometimes not. I don't understand what is it depends from.
Where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Found a solution to store temporaryActiveUserKey so need to receive email from an active button press only once a month 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77454609/17137584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [`Session.getActiveUser()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser):

> Gets information about the current user. **If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank string.** The **circumstances** in which the email address is available **vary**: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user).

So this seems pretty expected and there is no hard workaround you can make to retrieve the users mail. You should maybe just ask for it and see if they be willingly want to give it to you.

Although if you are the developer or the users are inside your organization this restrictions may be ignored:

> However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same G Suite domain as the user.

Comment: You recognized my problem well. I want to get it with onEdit() trigger. I got some "success" with installed triggers onEdit and onChange. I install onEdit trigger for function with `getActiveUser()`-> edit sheet as many times as I want with function execution -> delete trigger. Each user can create a trigger for the project but success recognizing `ActiveUser` is happening with his own trigger. But this does not prevent the function being executed with triggers created by other users. So all next executions return `blank` and cover first result.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to ask directly for the email, with a dialog box or something. In the end this is kind of security stuff and is hard to manage because Google will protect users privacy.

Comment: @Timogavk: Your comment above helped me finally figure out how to get this working! The key is separate triggers for each user. Then I simply added code to execute the update only if the Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() call does not come back blank. Of course, because each's user's trigger will run, the function will execute x times where x = the number of users (i.e. triggers), but with the check for a blank return value the logic only runs once (and so no overwrites). A bit clumsy indeed, and perhaps not practical if you have more than a handful of users, but workable in my case. Thanks!

Comment: @b-frid how do you set a trigger for a specific user ?

Comment: @Leo Ma That's just thing thing... I don't. Rather, I have logic filtered by something like `if (user !== '') { ... } `. Then, if you want to do something specific for specific users, you continue as such: `if (user === 'your_desired_user') { ... }`. Again, the trigger will run x # of times, depending on how many users you have, but the logic in the filtered loop itself will only run for the active user. If you have a large number of users this may not be practical, but for only a few users it seems to work fine. Hope that helps.

Comment: And just in case it wasn't quite clear... `var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();`

Comment: @b-frid right, but the problem was that i couldn't get user's email, what worked fine was adding a trigger while signed in as the user. this might not be possible for everyOne of course , thanks for the response

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment by [b-frid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7649168).

The flow:

1. create a custom menu and tell each user to run the function twice. First time for authorization, and the second time to actually run the code.
2. this will install the same trigger with the user's privileges and let the onEdit trigger get the email of an active user (author of the trigger)

video-instruction:

https://www.loom.com/share/30b11e4d012447f7a1efdd9a7eac4fca

gist:

https://gist.github.com/Max-Makhrov/e3e89e7fe0c6e86b68a4be1262e53629

Code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu(' run me 2x times')
      .addItem('please let script to see your email', 'install')
      .addToUi();
}


// function test() {
//   var e = {
//     range: SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test_onEdit').getRange('B2')
//   }
//   edit_(e)
// }
function edit_(e) {
  var targetcol = 1;
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Sheet1') {
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    if (user !== '') {
      var col = e.range.getColumn();
      var rows = e.range.getHeight();
      var ratgetrange = e.range.offset(
        0,
        targetcol - col,
        rows,
        1);
      ratgetrange.setValue(user);
    }
  } 
}

function install() {
  setOnEditTrigger_(
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId(),
    'edit_');
}


/**
 * create onEdit trigger
 * 
 * @param {string} spreadsheetId
 * @param {string} functionName
 * 
 */
function setOnEditTrigger_(spreadsheetId, functionName) {
  console.log('OnEdit trigger ' + functionName +
     ' for new file' +
     spreadsheetId);
  var trigger;

  if (existsOnEditTrigger_(functionName, spreadsheetId)) {
    console.log('stopped execution. Trigger exists.');
    return;
  }

  trigger = ScriptApp
    .newTrigger(functionName)
    .forSpreadsheet(spreadsheetId)
    .onEdit()
    .create();  
  
  console.log('Created new trigger!')
  return trigger.getUniqueId();
}

/**
 * check if onEdit trigger exists
 * 
 * @param {string} spreadsheetId
 * @param {string} functionName
 * 
 */
function existsOnEditTrigger_(functionName, spreadsheetId) {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var trigger = {};  
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    trigger = triggers[i];
    if (
      trigger.getHandlerFunction() === functionName && 
      trigger.getTriggerSourceId() === spreadsheetId &&
      trigger.getEventType().toString() === 'ON_EDIT') return true;
  }  
  return false;
}
```

Original comment:

> The key is separate triggers for each user. Then I simply added code
> to execute the update only if the `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`
> call does not come back blank. Of course, because each's user's
> trigger will run, the function will execute x times where x = the
> number of users (i.e. triggers), but with the check for a blank return
> value the logic only runs once (and so no overwrites). A bit clumsy
> indeed, and perhaps not practical if you have more than a handful of
> users, but workable in my case.