Apps Script - Google Form to Send custom PDF email on Checkbox Tick in Google Form Responses sheet
I'm trying to create a Google Apps Script that automatically sends a PDF email based on a checkbox selection in a Google Form response sheet.
The trigger to send the PDF is when the checkbox is ticked under Approval column as shown in the snippet below:

Tried to run this code and it's not doing anything


function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const checkboxColumn = 19; // Adjust if needed

  // Check if the edited sheet is "Form Responses 1" and the edited column is the checkbox column
  if (sheet.getName() === "Form Responses 1" && e.range.getColumn() === checkboxColumn) {

    // If the checkbox is checked, proceed with creating and sending the PDF
    if (e.range.isChecked()) {
      const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
     

    const info = {
    'Timestamp': [rowData[1]],
    'Email Address': [rowData[2]],
    'What Happened ?': [rowData[3]],
    'Why is it a Problem ?': [rowData[4]],
    'Who Detected /  Who is Affected ?': [rowData[5]],
    'Where is the Problem ?': [rowData[6]],
    'When Detected ?': [rowData[7]],
    'How was it Detected': [rowData[8]],
    'How Many ?': [rowData[9]],
    'Part Number ': [rowData[10]],
    'Type of the component ': [rowData[11]],
    'Camera Stage': [rowData[12]],
    'Quantity to be blocked by PN': [rowData[13]],
    'Proposed disposition plan': [rowData[14]],
    'Due Date ': [rowData[15]],
    'Comment': [rowData[16]]
    };

    const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
    sheet.getRange(entryRow, 20).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
    sendEmail(info["Email Address"][0], pdfFile);
    }
  }
}

function createPDF(info) {
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ejP3Dsd4y4TiIjtsJ3fHf5g_cmjvHDbo");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1cvIus2hbg25W3SgqeLP30Fc4661k_HR6");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1sfZGb1jo0amoOFB1p_P-1UNyu_gKUDb8ReUnFNeQkBM");

  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();

  // Extract first and last name from email address
  const email = info['Email Address'][0] || "";
  const names = email.split(".");
  const firstName = names[0];
  const lastName = names.length > 1 ? names[1] : "";

  body.replaceText("{Date of Request}", info['Timestamp'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Requestor}", info['Email Address'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{What}", info['What Happened ?'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Why}", info['Why is it a Problem ?'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Who}", info['Who Detected /  Who is Affected ?'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Where}", info['Where is the Problem ?'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{When}", info['When Detected ?'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{How}", info['How was it Detected'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Qty}", info['How Many ?'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{PN}", info['Part Number '][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Type}", info['Type of the component '][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Stage}", info['Camera Stage'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Qty B}", info['Quantity to be blocked by PN'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Plan}", info['Proposed disposition plan'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Due}", info['Due Date'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Comment}", info['Comment'][0] || "");

  openDoc.saveAndClose();

  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + info['Part Number or Serial Number'][0]);
  //tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);  
  newTempFile.setTrashed(true);
  return pdfFile;

}


function sendEmail(email, pdfFile) {
  const subjectUser = "Here's your QC930 Quarantine Entry Form";
  const bodyUser = "Hello,\n\nThank you for submitting a quarantine entry form request. \n\nPlease print and attach this form to all quarantined parts. \n\nMany thanks for your cooperation. \n\nKind regards, \nQuality Team";

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subjectUser, bodyUser, {
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'Quality Team'
  });

}




It's unclear how the afterFormSubmit function is called. In any case, the error means that e is undefined. One of the most common reasons for similar questions in Stack Overflow is that the function was called from the script editor.

how can this be fixed? will appreciate any suggestions

This might help How can I test a trigger function in GAS?

Is there an error message? Show your executions tab: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/

@TheMaster TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source') onEdit@ Code.gs:2

@MichelleP Like I said in my answer(see link in my previous comment), if you directly run the code from the script editor that error occurs. That is not the real error. You need to figure out the actual error.

@TheMaster yes you're correct. Ran the code again after ticking the box in the sheet and the error was gone.  However, another error came up in the createPDF function where "Email Address" is undefined. Not sure why when it's already declared  in the "info". Any idea how to fix this?
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Email Address')
createPDF @ Code.gs:52

@MichelleP How did you run the function? Did you  only check the checkbox or Did you run the createPdf in the script editor?

@TheMaster I tick all the checkbox in the response sheet and ran createPDF in the script editor

@MichelleP You should NOT run createPDF in the script editor. When you check a checkbox,  onEdit  function runs automatically, When onEdit function runs, this line const pdfFile = createPDF(info)... calls createPDF function and it also runs automatically. If you check the executions tab in the script editor, you'll see the type of execution, which will be a Trigger(like onEdit) and not Editor(Script editor). Btw, to send emails/create pdfs, you need installable  edit trigger and not a simple one: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65302896/ I believe that'll solve your actual issue
